# Where should I define custom routes in my ZF 1.10 app?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, routes

With the new `Zend_Application`/`Zend_Application_Bootstrap` classes I'm confused as to where I should be applying my custom routes. For example, at the moment I have one route:

```
protected function _initRouter() {
    $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite;
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('news/:id', 
        array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'));
    $router->addRoute('postArchive', $route);           
}
```

This method is in my `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` and is definitely run. The route is also applied in `$router`.

As I see it I could be doing two things wrong - either the wrong place to add these routes, or not adding to the correct router. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not passing the router to the front controller:

```
protected function _initRouter() 
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); // from singleton, for example
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('news/:id', 
        array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'));
    $router->addRoute('postArchive', $route);  

    return $router;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

resources.router.routes.www.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.www.route = ":module.domain.tld"
resources.router.routes.www.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"

This view lines in the application.ini file in the bootstrap section did the job for me...